# Power supply for micro(3.3) and LCD(5)

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, texas-instruments, linear-regulator

I am designing a board that has an LCD and msp430fr2433. They both need 5v and 3.3v respectively. So I decided to use TPS560430X3FDBVR and TLV70033DSET to provide 5v and 3.3v. I have attached the schematic and traced the path with a yellow highlighter. I hope this makes it easy to follow.

I followed the circuit recommended by the datasheets of the regulators except for Cboot which is 1uF on the board. Is anything wrong with my schematic?

Problem: I connected the board to a 12V DC power supply. It's pulling 3A. Seems like there is a short but nothing is burning. Not sure why there is a 3A draw when the 5V regulator output current is 0.6A max.

I didn't find any short but the 3.3V regulator and micro pads are underneath the component. I can't see if there's a short.

Analysis: If there is nothing wrong with my schematic, I plan on concluding that there is a short. I just want to get a second opinion about the schematic.

Datasheets:

5v regulator https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps560430.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1606594508057

3.3v regulator https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv700.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1606600030251

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The TPS560430X3F is a fixed 3.3V model, so you are using the wrong regulator model.

It seems that what you wanted was the adjustable TPS560430XF model, i.e. "XF" instead of "X3F".

The incorrect regulator does not work in the circuit meant for adjustable model, and has damaged the rest of the components with overvoltage.

Explanation:

If read the datasheet correctly, the fixed 3.3V version has the feedback reference voltage of 3.3V instead of 1.0V, so the feedback resistors try to set the regulator output to 16.5V.

So basically the 5V node has most likely had serious overvoltage, and it's exceeded the ratings of all 5V powered components, and they are damaged. For example the 3.3 LDO has absolute maximum rating of 6V, so chances are everything powered by it is also damaged.

Edit: After changing to correct adjustable regulator component, apply the input supply with the proper polarity.

Comment: I understand. I used a 3.3V fixed regulator and had the circuitry which was meant for an adjustable regulator. This gave 16V which might have blown the components on the other side resulting in a short. Hence it's pulling 3A, which is the maximum current that my DC power supply permits.

If I replace it with the following component, the circuit would work fine? 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/TPS560430XFDBVR/9692650

Comment: You can check the datasheet if the part number matches what you need.

Comment: I did .. That's the one that is adjustable. The circuit around it gives 5V output. I was just double-checking .. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So I brought the correct component and soldered on a brand new board. The same thing happened. Now sure why? There's literally nothing connected after the output capacitor of the regulator. It's impossible to have a short. Seems like there is a design flaw that I can't see. Can anybody see what I can't see?

Comment: So there is another issue. Can you add more info, like schematic layout and list of the components (inductors, resistors and capacitors) around the TPS560430, and photo of the board area with aforementioned parts?

Comment: VR3(3.3V linear regulator) is not populated. Only VR5 (Switching regulator 5V) and its components to get 5V are populated. It's impossible to have a short as it's not connected to anything. I've connected the board to a 5V (DC power supply) and limited the current to 1A. The power supply is giving out 1.3V only. It increases slightly when I increase the current limit to 2A but there is smoking coming out. This leads me to believe that there is a short for sure. Something is wrong with my circuit.

Comment: I'm even thinking of going back to a 5V linear regulator. I used them before and dint have a problem. This is my first experience with a switching regulator.  

Please look at the attached image. The components inside the yellow highlighter are populated on the board. Nothing else.

Comment: It's difficult to see from the blurry picture, but I see suspicious things. Tell me, what pin numbering you used on the PCB footprint of the TPS chip? It could be wrong. Also, this may not cause the issue, but the components that need to be close to the regulator is scattered all around the circuit, which makes no sense.

Comment: The pins on the schematic match the pins on the footprint. I check all the pins against the datasheet as well. Eg: Pin 4 & 5 are Vin and en and they are connected to 12V on the PCB. I check others as well. Nothing wrong here. The components are not far away from each other. Its just appears like that when I zoomed in. I have attached the pic of the whole PCB. YOu can see that they are close to each other.

Comment: OK, so pinout is fine then. Can you post the datasheets or links to the components around the converter, i.e. the inductor and the capacitors? And you have most likely used a multimeter to check the PCB for shorts and verified the resistor values? Where does the smoke come from?

Comment: Here are the datasheets: 

88.7K https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/RK73H.pdf

22.1K https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/RK73H.pdf

10uH https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/inductor_automotive_decoupling_nlcv32-efrd_en.pdf

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tdk-corporation/C2012X5R1V226M125AC/3956094

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tdk-corporation/C2012X5R1V226M125AC/3956094

Comment: It could be the inductor. The XF version runs at 1.1 MHz so suggested value is 18uH. The inductor max current is also significantly less than suggested peak switching current of 1.4A for 600mA DC load. But lesser ratings should be OK if 600mA is not needed. Which parameters you designed the components with? 12V in, 5V out, 1.1 MHz frequency, what is max DC load?

Comment: The Max DC load should be around 70mA. I'm nowhere near the peak. I was thinking of getting rod of the switching regulator and its components. I'll make a new board and it will just have a 12V input which will be become 5V after a linear voltage regulator and then another linear voltage regulator to get 3.3V. That is it. what do you think?

Comment: I found the problem. I label 12V and GND incorrectly. SO all this time, the VR was connected in reverse. I checked multiple times but I checked against the labels which were incorrect. Once I fixed that, I'm getting 5V out. I'm really really sorry for the trouble. This was a very very ridiculous mistake on my part.

Comment: Great! It is also an important part to not assume the basic things like silkscreen markings when bringing up new boards and verifying the design, so technically it was not a huge design error or failure. I was slightly worried about the PCB component placement and routing being the issue, as I still think it should be better. Plus, I did catch the wrong regulator so even if you had polarity correct to begin with it would have still exploded. I'll formulate an answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. When you say "I still think it should be better". Where do you think I should make improvements for my next board.